# URL rewrite replace string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I am trying to replace a word in URL and redirect the user using .htaccess

I have this link,

```
/anyword/akram/anyotherword
```

and I would like to redirect user to

```
/anyword/tanger/anyotherword
```

Here is the code I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)akram(.*)$ $1tanger$2 [R=301,L]
```

**Edit**

Virtualhost:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mywebsite.com/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
            RewriteRule ^(.+)/akram/(.+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/tanger/$2 [R=301,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this rule.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/akram/(.+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/tanger/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
because I have this rule             RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L] in the previous line.
It work only if add app.php 
http://example.com/app.php/akram work
but http://example.com/akram doesn't work.

Comment: Put exactly what you need it to do. And show the rest of your htaccess rules in your question. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. You need to clarify more.

Comment: I have website that is developed with symfony, my front controller is app.php. I need to replace any string in url ''akram" by "tanger".
I have edited my post and added my config

Comment: Add the rule before your symfony. All rewrites will go there first. Move it above that. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

you should create a new file and save it as .htaccess 
After that . Edit the contents of the file. For 301 (Permanent) Redirect: Point an entire site to a different URL on a permanent basis.

```
# This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain
Redirect 301 / http://***/anyword/tanger/anyotherword
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering quite late. 
but I think somebody can get it helpful..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /akram/ /tanger/
```

checkout 
[Open link, and click on "test"](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/?url=http://somesite.com/anyword/akram/anyotherword&htaccess=RewriteRule%20/akram/%20/tanger/)